# JMF using javax.imageio issue

Tags: java, swing, image-processing, jmf

I have created this simple program that uses the JMF to capture a webcam image and save it to the local harddrive with arguments. It works great when using the `com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.*` from ecplipse.  But JDK7 does not support this anymore. Can´t be compiled from commandline. Instead I have to use the `javax.imageio`. But I´m stuck here. Can´t finish the code. I replaced the `com.sun.image.codec.jpeg` with `javax.imageio`.

```
ImageIO.write(buffImg, "png", new File("c:\\byder_"+imagebydernr+".png"));
```

when run it from ecplipse it gives this error

```
"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
Exception in thread "main"
```

Don't know what to do. Do I need to make a class for the imageIO.?

```
package SwingCapture;


import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.format.*;
import javax.media.util.*;
import javax.media.control.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.imageio.*;



public class SwingCapture extends Panel implements ActionListener 
{
 /**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static Player player = null;
public CaptureDeviceInfo di = null;
public MediaLocator ml = null;
public JButton capture_take = null;
public JButton capture_accept = null;
public static Buffer buf = null;
public Image img = null;
public VideoFormat vf = null;
public BufferToImage btoi = null;
public ImagePanel imgpanel = null;
public BufferedImage buffImg = null;
public static String imagebydernr = null;



public SwingCapture() 
{
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
setSize(320,550);

imgpanel = new ImagePanel();
capture_take = new JButton("Take picture");
capture_accept = new JButton("Accept picture");
capture_take.addActionListener(this);
capture_accept.addActionListener(this);

String str2 = "vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0";
di = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice(str2);
ml = di.getLocator();


try 
{
  player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(ml);
  player.start();
  Component comp;

  if ((comp = player.getVisualComponent()) != null)
  {
    add(comp,BorderLayout.NORTH);
  }
  add(capture_take,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(capture_accept,BorderLayout.EAST);
  add(imgpanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
 }



 public void main(String[] args) 
 {
Frame f = new Frame("C5snap");
SwingCapture cf = new SwingCapture();

imagebydernr = args[0];


f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
  playerclose();
  System.exit(0);}});

f.add("Center",cf);
f.pack();
f.setSize(new Dimension(320,550));
f.setVisible(true);
}


public void playerclose() 
{
player.close();
player.deallocate();
 }


 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
 {
JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();

if (c == capture_take) 
{


     // Grab a frame from the capture device
    FrameGrabbingControl frameGrabber =                  (FrameGrabbingControl)player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");
    Buffer buf = frameGrabber.grabFrame();


    // Convert frame to an buffered image so it can be processed and saved
    Image img = (new BufferToImage((VideoFormat)buf.getFormat()).createImage(buf));
    BufferedImage buffImg = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null),     BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = buffImg.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, null, null);

    // Overlay current time on image
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 16));
    g.drawString((new Date()).toString(), 10, 25);


 // Show picture
    imgpanel.setImage(img);



} else if (c == capture_accept) {

    File f = new File("c:\\byder_"+imagebydernr+".png");


    if(f.exists()){
          System.out.println("File existed");


          /* Warning box, if file exist.*/ 
          Object[] options = { "close" };
          int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
              "File exist. Close and call new picture", 
              "Advarsel", 
              JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
              JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
              null, 
              options, 
              options[0]);

          // Closing applet 
        if (choice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
      {
        System.exit(0);
      }

     }else{
          System.out.println("File not found!");

           // Save image to disk as PNG
          ImageIO.write(buffImg, "png", new File("c:\\byder_"+imagebydernr+".png"));  

     }
    // Close webcam
    player.close();
    player.deallocate();
    System.exit(0);
    }    
 }


 class ImagePanel extends Panel 
 {
  /**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public Image myimg = null;

  public ImagePanel() 
 {
setLayout(null);
setSize(320,240);
 }

 public void setImage(Image img) 
 {
this.myimg = img;
repaint();
 }

  public void paint(Graphics g) 
 {
 if (myimg != null) 
 {
  g.drawImage(myimg, 0, 0, this);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Don't override `paint()` in a `JPanel` - use `paintComponent()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try..

public **static** void main(String[] args)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

and

```
public static void playerclose()
```

... then it should work.

Comment: Please use the formatting tools given by Stackoverflow, there are great and easy to use. Moreover, you can use the preview to see how your answer will look like. As stated here, your answer is hardly readable and will likely not help.